# HashMap: Error insert VariableDeclaratorId to complete FormalParameterList

Tags: java, hashmap

Java gives me this error: `Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameterList` when I try to add a resource through the **addResource** method:

```
private HashMap<String,Resource> resources = new HashMap<String, Resource>();       
private String id;
private Resource Resource;

private void addResource(Resource) {    
  resources.put(Resource);      
}
```

The error is thrown at me in Resource, as if I hadn't declared the type of parameter data.

> Error => Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type The method
>   put(String, Resource) in the type HashMap is not
>   applicable for the arguments
>   (Resource)    Catalogue.java  /PRAC3_ex2/src/PRAC3_ex2    line 32 Java
>   Problem

Comment: Map needs both *key* and *value* for each entry.

Comment: Also, do not give variable its type name. You will confuse yourself.

Comment: Okay, but this happens to the method: `catalogue1.addResource(book);`

Comment: Do you understand what `Map` is and what parameters `put()` requires?  See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-put-method-in-java-with-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Per the exception message

> The method put(String, Resource) in the type HashMap is not applicable
> for the arguments (Resource)

Your `resources` is a HashMap.  The `put` method requires both a key and a value.  I don't know what you should be using as a key here - it may be enough to do the following.

```
resources.put(resources.getResourceName(), resource);
```